# Other user's icon appeared in Google Sheets, no explanation

Tags: google-sheets

When I mouse over the A, first I see a tooltip showing my coworker's full name "Abel Jones" (for example), and then a larger pop out showing his full name and presumably the default Google+ profile image.

[image: Upper Right corner of Google Sheets browser window]

I just want to know what Google Sheets is trying to tell me.

Why did he suddenly appear there?

Hint: I recently asked him to go to Tools/Notifications Rules and make it so he is notified when I make changes.

Is his "A" icon telling me that he succeeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that other users had opened the file while you have opened it and that you could chat using the Google Docs editor built-in chat tool. For further details see [Chat with others in a file](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494891?hl=en)